# How to Insert Data with Mysql Trigger After Insert?

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is the database vehicle table's trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS InsertVehTrig;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER InsertVehTrig AFTER INSERT
ON Vehicle FOR EACH ROW
   SWL_return:
BEGIN
   DECLARE Cph CHAR(50);
   DECLARE DevID CHAR(12);
   DECLARE VehID BIGINT;
   DECLARE TmpID BIGINT;
   DECLARE DevCount INT;

   SET Cph = rtrim(ltrim(NEW.cph));
   SET VehID = NEW.ID;
   SET DevID = NEW.DevID;

   if(VehID is null) then 
    select count(id) into @DevCount from vehicle where (cph=@Cph) or (DevID=@DevID);
-- 条件：当前的车牌号　或　设备ID
    end if;

   if (DevCount > 1) then  -- 如果记录数，超过1，则认为有重复   
      -- Rollback not supported in trigger
        SET @SWV_Null_Var = 0;
        Leave SWL_return;
   else 
      if (DevCount = 1) then
         select ID INTO @TmpID from Vehicle where (Vehicle.cph = @Cph) or (Vehicle.DevID = @DevID);
         if (TmpID != VehID) then -- --如果增加的车牌号码与数据库中的在相同的，则不允许增加
            -- Rollback not supported in trigger
                Leave SWL_return;
                SET @SWV_Null_Var = 0;
         end if;
      end if;
   end if;

   update vehicle set cph = @Cph where ID = @VehID;
END;
```

Right now i m trying to insert new data row in the vehicle table, but error with this

```
ERROR 1442: Can't update table 'vehicle' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

SQL Statement:

INSERT INTO `gis_server`.`vehicle` (`TrackerNum`, `cph`, `DevID`, `DevType`) VALUES ('1', 'NR09B00555', 'NR09B00555', '2')
```

those database are designed by 3 party company,
How do i insert data to vehicle table?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making two changes to your approach:

- Firstly, use a `BEFORE` trigger rather than an `AFTER`
- Secondly, rather than updating the same table, update the `NEW` table, setting the column value to the new value before the `NEW` table hits the table targeted by the `INSERT`.

For example, replace your `UPDATE` line with the following:

```
UPDATE NEW SET cph = Cph;
```

MySQL doesn't allow you to edit the data in the table on which a trigger is created in that trigger, but you can edit the `NEW` table to modify the values going into that table.

Comment: i don't understand about the new table side, how to declare the new table? i m new for triggers, pls help

Comment: Must After Insert? If not how to use the Update Statement? need to change to use Insert statement? because haven't insert to new row, how to update it?

Comment: i have changed table name to NEW, but returned error `ERROR 1146: Table 'gis_server.NEW' doesn't exist`